# Efficiency of std::bind vs lambda

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda, stdbind

I have searched around a bit and found many examples and discussions of cases where you would use `std::bind` instead of a lambda, but the burning question I have is whether or not there is any performance benefit to one over the other. I will describe my use case:

I have a generic `A*` I have implemented, to which I pass successor, heuristic distance, and move cost functions.

Here is an example of my heuristic function ready to be passed off for a search (in both forms):

```
std::function<float(const Location*, const Location*)> hdist = std::bind(&TerrainMap::straightLineDist, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

std::function<float(const Location*, const Location*)> hdist2 = [this](const Location* a, const Location* b){
    return straightLineDist(a,b);
};
```

Is there any difference in the performance of these approaches? I realize the difference is probably negligible but I am curious enough to want to know.

Comment: Profile to be sure.

Comment: Alternatively look at the [assembler code](https://godbolt.org/g/uh8iQh). I can't read assembler properly, but I can see that the bind version has a lot more of it.

Comment: In both cases you should probably be using `auto`.  The biggest advantage for the lambda (the compiler knows the exact type and can optimize more aggressively) is lost when you assign to an `std::function`.

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the exact compiler brand and version, and yes, inspecting assembly and profiling are two generally useful tools for that.  But also, if any `bind` expression does perform better than a directly equivalent lambda, that would be evidence of a missed opportunity for the compiler to optimize the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the performance of these approaches?

Perhaps, perhaps not; as commenters suggest - profile to check, or look at the assemby code you get (e.g. using the [GodBolt Compiler Explorer](http://www.godbolt.org/)). But you're asking the wrong question, for two main reasons:

1. You should probably not be passing lambda's, nor `bind()` results, around in the part of your code that's performance-critical.
2. You should *definitely* avoid invoking arbitrary functions via function pointer or `std::function` variables in performance-critical areas of your code (except if this can be de-virtualized and inlined by the compiler).

and one mind reason:

3. Lambdas (and `std::bind()`'s) are usable, and useful, without being wrapped in std::function; this wrapper has its own performance penalty, so you would only be comparing one way of using these constructs.

Bottom line recommendation: Just use Lambdas. They're cleaner, easier to understand, cheaper to compile, and more flexible syntactically. So don't worry and be happy :-) . And in performance-critical code, either use Lambda's without `std::function`, or don't use any of the two.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In my case I was passing function pointers to make my A* more generic `template <typename S, typename D> QLinkedList<S> astar(std::function<QLinkedList<S>(S)> getSuccessors, std::function<D(S,S)> gdist, std::function<D(S)> hdist, S start) {`